# How to speak and write advance level English in 6 months?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, vocabulary, learning, learning-methods

I have been learning English language for a long time. But, neither my writing nor speaking isn't on the level I desire it to be. Furthermore, I'm not fully comfortable with English. I want to learn it so good that I can express my thoughts in English as good as my mother tongue. Hence, I have decided to rigoursly practice it for 6 months on my own.

My current plan is like this:-

Everyday I'm spending 2-3 hours understanding and memorising grammar rules from a grammar book. Thereafter,I give 1 hour memorising vocabularies, 1 hour for phrasal verbs, 1 hour on idoms and a hour reading English books.

Do you think this a good way to learn? Anything else I should be doing?

Comment: This is a bit too general to answer in this format see the [tour] for the sort of questions that work well here.  General advice, if you use long words, make sure you use them correctly (You have been learning, not "inculcating".  Are you sure that others would describe your writing as "effervescent"). And  "by myself" never works for anything involving "communication"

Answer (score 1):

Despite problems with the question as stated and perhaps even its location here I believe we need to answer questions if we are able to.

Those sound like noble goals but I think you could reduce them greatly if you would add many more hours to **Reading English in books**. This will do more to tell you how the other subjects you mention are actually used. This usage will make more sense to you than mere memorization. Many questions found here start with rules memorized that somehow do not work.

After I read from one author or another I end up talking like them for a time. This is how usage is learned best, not from memorizing rule after rule. Once you find something in a book you cannot understand then get the rules out for study. You always study best with questions in mind, not just goals.  Good luck.